# Debugging in VS Code in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

so i have a problem with debugging a program in VS Code in Ubuntu. When i try that i get this message launch:program 'enter program name, for example /home/daniel/Desktop/OOP/Test/a.out'does not exist  and i have an option to see the launch.json file. So any ideas what is the problem? And whats wrong?

Here is the launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAt`enter code here`Entry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `"program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out"` speak for itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line

"program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",

to this

"program": "/home/daniel/Desktop/OOP/Test/a.out",

Comment: Yes, this helped. But when i try to debug and add a breakpoint somewhere, the debugger stops. I mean i have written a one line code and tried the debugger with a breakpoint on it, but it stops and i cant go through the code line by line with the debugger. Why?